# Toilet repeatedly clogs - is putting toilet bowl cleaner in the toilet's tank causing the problem?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, cleaning, clog

Our apartment's toilet repeatedly clogs.  My roommate puts toilet bowl cleaner in the toilet's tank, so that when we flush, the cleaning liquid runs through the toilet.  I'm starting to wonder if the toilet bowl cleaner is clogging the jets and causing the toilet to repeatedly clog.  Can putting toilet bowl cleaner in the tank clog the jets?  Could this be contributing to the repeat clogs?

Comment: Toilet bowel cleaner shouldn't be an issue. Did it always clog or is it a new issue? Is it a high efficiency or low efficiency toilet?

Answer (score 2):

If by "clog" you mean

- You try to flush,
- *Water flows into the bowl,*
- The water level stabilizes *higher* than the normal resting level and the toilet doesn't actually flush.

Then I really can't imagine any way the cleaner fluid could be causing it.

In any case, check the directions on the cleaner product in question. It's certainly possible for an improperly used cleaning product to cause other problems in in a device like a toilet; I'd specifically be worried about some of the soft or hinged gaskets degrading.

Answer (score 2):

Toilets clog because too much is going through a small hole.   Not because of cleaner.   Things that might help.

- use less toilet paper.
- courtesy flush
- buy more "industrial" type toilet paper, you know the stuff you get at your work - all the 6-ply quilted stuff will clog quickly if there are any issues.   This stuff takes a long time to break down and sticks to itself well.   Might feel good but smaller exit lines don't do well with it.
- get more water in your tank - adjust the water level
- make sure nothing else goes down the toilet - trash, "flushable wipes", whatever.

There are probably a few other things but if your apartment isn't going to change the lines you have to adjust what you are doing.   The cleaner has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting repeat clogs, and this is an apartment. Most likely something was put down the toilet and its jammed in there. Last apartment I pulled out a toy army man out of the toilet with my automotive claw tool: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your maximum water level in the tank. The water level should sit just below the overflow tube. If you are able to adjust your fill valve or float (ballcock-style) to allow more water in the tank, you will get a more powerful flush. Try to wobble the toilet. If you have considerable movement, time for a new wax seal. If the seal hasn't been replaced in a while, that would be a cheap upgrade.